# Brouwer fixed-point for open ball and bijective uniformly continuous function?

Tags: gn.general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Let $B^-$ be the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and let $f$ be a uniformly continuous function from $B^-$ to itself, with a uniformly continuous inverse $f^{-1}$.

Under these conditions, must $f$ have a fixed point in $B^-$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, for instance a piecewise-linear (say with two pieces) bijection $f:(0,1)\to(0,1)$ whose graph lies on one side of the diagonal $y=x$.

Comment: thank you! I must admit I thought it was harder...but it's also very nice to get a short and clear answer. Cheers, Frank (I understand the vote to close, by the way...but that's how it sometimes goes)

Comment: So now I'll start thinking again about which natural extra conditions on $f$ would ensure a fixed point in the open ball...